# Choosing a free geolocation database

Tags: geolocation, maxmind, ip-geolocation, ip2location

We are looking for a free (or not so expensive) downloadable geolocation database (not the online service). Would like to get following information:

```
1. IP -> Country
2. IP -> City
3. IP -> Connection Speed
4. Lat/Long -> City
```

I found many online services but that's not what I am looking for. I found following options for downloadable databases although they don't provide all the features.

```
1. maxmind GeoLite2  
2. ip2nation
3. ip2location lite
```

Any comments on relative accuracy of these databases? Also, any suggestions  IP --> connection speed db? Maxmind provides IP --> connection speed DB but quite expensive and at this moment we do not have budget.

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

Both Maxmind and IP2Location are doing good in term of accuracy. They have been in geolocation industry since the very beginning.

Both of them also offer connection speed database.

Maxmind [$370 + $90/month]
https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-connection-type-database

IP2Location DB13 [$649/year]
https://www.ip2location.com/databases/db13-ip-country-region-city-latitude-longitude-timezone-netspeed